# How can I use the user instead of the user_id / sub assigned to me by the OIDC provider with kubelogin?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Im using mimikube for test, I would like to know if the username can be used instead of the sub provided by oidc provider

```
minikube start  --extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=RBAC,Node \
--extra-config=apiserver.oidc-issuer-url=$ISSUER_URL \
--extra-config=apiserver.oidc-client-id=$CLIENT_ID \
--extra-config=apiserver.oidc-username-claim=sub
```

then I configure kubelogin

```
kubectl oidc-login setup \
--oidc-issuer-url=$ISSUER_URL \
--oidc-client-id=$CLIENT_ID \
--oidc-client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET
```

Then the application provides me the next steps

```
## 2. Verify authentication

You got a token with the following claims:

{
  "iss": REDACTED,
  "sub": REDACTED_SUB,
  "aud": REDACTED,
  "iat": REDACTED,
  "exp": REDACTED,
  "nonce": REDACTED
}

## 3. Bind a cluster role

Run the following command:

    kubectl create clusterrolebinding oidc-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=REDACTED_SUB

## 4. Set up the Kubernetes API server

Add the following options to the kube-apiserver:

    --oidc-issuer-url=REDACTED
    --oidc-client-id=REDACTED

## 5. Set up the kubeconfig

Run the following command:

    kubectl config set-credentials oidc \
      --exec-api-version=client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1 \
      --exec-command=kubectl \
      --exec-arg=oidc-login \
      --exec-arg=get-token \
      --exec-arg=--oidc-issuer-url=ISSUER_URL \
      --exec-arg=--oidc-client-id=CLIENT_ID \
      --exec-arg=--oidc-client-secret=CLIENT_SECRET

## 6. Verify cluster access

Make sure you can access the Kubernetes cluster.

    kubectl --user=oidc get nodes

You can switch the default context to oidc.

    kubectl config set-context --current --user=oidc
```

if I set the step 3 with username oidc instead of REDACTED_SUB I get this error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User REDACTED_SUB cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

How can I use the username instead of REDACTED_SUB?

Answer (score 0):

Set the subject name in your OIDC to "oidc" it should work. Otherwise you are using a name that; when K8s asks your OIDC to authenticate, your OIDC doesn't recognize that name (subject).